# Building Expression to search in child properies (collection) of object

Tags: c#, linq, expression, linq-expressions

I have a search setup to return matching `Record` objects based on criteria. It builds an Expression Tree based on the type of criteria and queries the database to return matches. Previously, it only matched on top-level properties, but now I'm trying to search within child properties of `Record` and build an Expression that may be combined with others in a query. The objects look like this:

```
public class Record
{
    public virtual ICollection<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public Guid AttributeId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual Record Record { get; set; }
}
```

One of the possible criteria is a value pair of `AttributeId` and `Value`, for which I would return all `Record` rows which have an `Attribute` matching both values. For example, if I was just writing a simple LINQ query it would look like this:

```
Guid searchId = Guid.NewGuid();
string searchValue = "asdf";

IQueryable<Record> records = GetSomeQueryToRecords();
IEnumerable<Record> recordsThatMatch = records
    .Where(r => r.Attribute.Any(a => a.AttributeId == searchId && a.Value == searchValue));
```

I need to instead build this into my Expression tree so it will work both in-memory and for EF Core queries. The Expression returned by `GetExpression` would end up being combined with other Expressions using `AndAlso` to build a large query down the line. I have tried this:

```
ParameterExpression record = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Record));
Expression searchExpression = GetExpression(record, searchId, searchValue);

Expression<Func<Record, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lamda<Func<Record, bool>>(searchExpression, record);
recordsThatMatch = records.Where(lambda);


private Expression GetExpression(ParameterExpression parameter, Guid searchId, string searchValue)
{
    // Get the Record.Attributes Memboer.
    MemberExpression attributes = Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(Record.Attributes));

    // Get the "record.Attributes.Any(predicate)" Method.
    MethodInfo anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
        .Where(m => m.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Any))
        .Where(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
        .Single();
    
    // Make Method generic.
    anyMethod = anyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Attribute));

    ParameterExpression attribute = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Attribute));

    Expression idEqualExpression = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(attribute, nameof(Attribute.AttributeId)),
        Expression.Constant(searchId)
    );

    Expression valueEqualExpression = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(attribute, nameof(Attribute.Value)),
        Expression.Constant(searchValue)
    );

    Expression attributeMatchExpression = Expression.AndAlso(idEqualExpression, valueEqualExpression);

    return Expression.Call(null, anyMethod, attributes, attributeMatchExpression);
}
```

I get an `ArgumentException` with `Expression.Call` though, because honestly I don't know how to use it for this particular instance and it has many overrides. I believe I should be passing `null` since I actually want a static method as `.Any()` is an extension method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to create 'LambdaExpresson'. Also `Expression.Call` can besimplified.

```cs
private Expression GetExpression(ParameterExpression parameter, Guid searchId, string searchValue)
{
    // Get the Record.Attributes Memboer.
    MemberExpression attributes = Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(Record.Attributes));

    ParameterExpression attribute = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Attribute));

    Expression idEqualExpression = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(attribute, nameof(Attribute.AttributeId)),
        Expression.Constant(searchId)
    );

    Expression valueEqualExpression = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(attribute, nameof(Attribute.Value)),
        Expression.Constant(searchValue)
    );

    Expression attributeMatchExpression = Expression.AndAlso(idEqualExpression, valueEqualExpression);

    var matchLambda = Expression.Lambda(attributeMatchExpression, attribute);

    return Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Any), new [] {typeof(Attribute)}, attributes, matchLambda);
}
```